# While controller to book all the products

Tags: jmeter

I have extracted an array (contains 6 products) using regex extract post processor. Now I want to add all the products to cart until it reaches `matchNr`. how can I achieve with help of while controller.

Please give me the logic:

[image]

I want to add that transaction under while controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 6 matches which look like

```
productID_1=1111
productID_2=2222
productID_3=3333
productID_4=4444
productID_5=5555
productID_6=6666
productID_matchNr=6
```

and want to add them to cart one by one it makes more sense to consider using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)

[image]

[image]

### [image]

If for some reason you want to use the While Controller it's also possible but it's more tricky

1. Use the following [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) as the condition:

   ```
   ${__groovy((vars.get('__jm__While Controller__idx') ?: 0) as int < vars.get('productID_matchNr') as int,)}
   ```
2. Use [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) functions combination to refer the current value of the productID

   ```
   ${__V(productID_${__intSum(${__jm__While Controller__idx},1,)},)}
   ```

[image]